# How can we get random option value from the dropdown list in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, dropdown, response, html-select

What the below code like:

```
<td style="width:150px;">
                <select id="ddlMgrMpng" onchange="changeMgr('140')" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option value="first" selected="selected">
                        First Me
                    </option>
                    <option value="second">
                        Second Me
                    </option>
                </select>
            </td>
```

How can I capture values "First Me" and "Second Me" in jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below CSS extractor:-

[image]

Use the same in "CSS/JQuery Extractor".

Hope this helps.